# If $G$ is an abelian group, then $H=\{g\in G \mid |g| \text{ divides }12\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

$$H=\{g\in G \mid |g| \text{ divides }12\}$$

We have to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Consider $a\in G$ and, the group $\langle a \rangle$ where $|a|=12$. This group will contain elements orders of which will be divide 12. This is a cyclic subgroup I think this should be equal to H but I am not sure as I don't know if G is finite.

Comment: If you have $G = \Bbb Z_{12}\times \Bbb Z_{12}$, then $H = G$ but $H$ isn't cyclic. So your idea with $\langle a\rangle$ doesn't work. For another reason it doesn't work, if $G = \Bbb Z_4$, then once again $H = G$, but no element has order $12$.

Comment: You can not be sure that such an element $a$ exists in general. For all we know, $H$ could be as small as the $1$-element group $\{e\}$.

Comment: is the number $12$ significant somehow?

Comment: How else can I approach this?

Comment: @Alvin yes that is another part of the question.

Comment: How would you normally prove a statement like "Show that the subset $A$ of a group $B$ is actually a subgroup"? I would guess that you have a list of three properties, including something very much like "$e\in A$". Try those, and if you can't do them all, come back here with all your results and we'll help you get the rest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** We can rewrite $H=\{g\in G\mid 12g=0\}$.  Therefore, if you can show that the map $g\mapsto 12g$ is a homomorphism, then you have that $H$ is the kernel of a homomorphism and therefore a subgroup.

Comment: I have just started so I haven't covered homorphisms yet so I couldn't think in this direction, but I understand the idea based on my Linear algebra knowledge. Great solve thanks.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar You can use the rewriting without talking about homomorphisms.  Show that if $12g=0$, then $12(-g)=0$, if $12g=12h=0$, then $12(g+h)=0$, and $12(0)=0$. There are more things to check this way, but it is still straight forward.

Comment: Yes that's how I solved it. I based it on ArsenBerk's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of seeking a specific example like cyclic groups, you can prove it in a more general way:

**HINT:** $H \le G$ if and only if

**1)** $H$ is not empty.

**2)** $H$ is closed under binary operation of $G$.

**3)** $H$ is closed under inverses.

Comment: "actually **2)** and **3)** implies **1)** but we need to ensure $H$ is non-empty." Then **2)** and **3)** do not imply **1)**. **2)** and **3)** together with "**1')** $H$ is non-empty" imply **1)**.

Comment: Oh, that is really logical.

Comment: Yes, we do assume that. It's a convention called [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), and it often does seem counterintuitive to people when they first encounter it. But it works better with all our other logic than any alternative.

Comment: Well, after I asked, I thought that it is not counter-intuitive because in an empty set, there is no element that breaks closure under binary operation or closure under inverses. I will check "vacuous truth" out, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the lemma $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $\forall a,b \in H : ab^{-1} \in H$ .
Assume $a,b \in H $ then $(ab^{-1})^{12} = a^{12}(b^{12})^{-1} $ and since $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ divide $12$ we have $a^{12}=b^{12}=e $. This implies $(ab^{-1})^{12}=e $ so $o(ab^{-1}) \mid 12 $ and this means $ab^{-1} \in H $.

**Note** : $a^n=e \Leftrightarrow o(a) \mid n$ .

Answer (score 0):

The key ingredient is that if $a,b $ commute, then $|ab|=\rm {lcm}(|a|,|b|) $.  From this we get closure.

The other key ingredient gives us inverses:  $|a^{-1}|=|a|$.

Don't forget to check that $H\ne\emptyset $.  We see that  $e\in H $.